# Resizing multiple images under the same id in css

Tags: html, css, image

I have just started learning HTML and CSS and I am implementing all the techniques I have learnt. I have come across a problem where I have two images places under one id that have 2 different dimensions. However I don't know how to edit them separately.
This is my HTML code:

```css
#main-header {
  background-color: #453e32;
}

#main-header img {
  height: 4%;
  width: 4%;
}

#main-header h1 {
  color: #F8D115;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  <img src="../resources/wsimplylogo.png" />
  <img src="../resources/wsimply.png" />
</div>
```

When editing the image sizes I cannot edit one specifically and I don't know if I should create another id separately or what
Any help would be appreciated!
PS I've literally only just started!

Comment: You can add ids or classes to each image, or you could even use the nth-child CSS selector, but that might be really out of your current knowledge. Stack Overflow is not really the best place for this sort of basic question. Try freecodecamp to better learn HTML + CSS, and their forum is a much better suited place for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everything given is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the selector `#main-header img` you target all img tags within your div with the id `main-header`. This means, that you cannot target a specific image without using something a bit more sofisticated.

If you're just learning css and html, I would suggest you give each of your images a seperate id (or class).

BUT if you really want to learn, then you could use `:nth-child()` as a selector:

```
#main img:nth-child(1){
  /*here be style of 1st image*/
}
```

For further reference, see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped me so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of **adjacent sibling selector +** css selector.

> **[*The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**

Also remove the closing `</img>` tag in your html. No need of it

```css
#main-header {
  background-color: #453e32;
}

#main-header img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#main-header img+img { /*for the second image followed by image*/
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
</div>
```